# C# Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.ConsoleKey' to 'char'

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, console-application

The following C# code I wrote gives me an error:

```
switch (Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar)
{
    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        break;
}
```

The error:

> Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.ConsoleKey' to 'char'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What's wrong?

Comment: You are using a System.ConsoleKey somewhere .Net is expecting a char (in a method argument or in an assignment maybe?). The problem is not in the code you provided though.

Comment: @Falanwe: The problem *is* in the code provided. Did you try compiling it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.key.aspx) property instead of the [`KeyChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.keychar.aspx) property.

```
switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
{
    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x,y);
        break;
}
```

The constant `ConsoleKey.DownArrow` is of type `ConsoleKey`, while `Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar` is of type `char`.

Since `char` and `ConsoleKey` are different types, this code can't compile.

Instead, if you use the [Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.key.aspx) property of the `ReadKey` return value, you get a `ConsoleKey`, which is of the same type as the cases in the switch statement.

Comment: @Witcher: Look at the types of the Key and KeyChar properties.

Answer (score 4):

You want the [`Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.key.aspx) property (which returns `ConsoleKey`), not [`KeyChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.keychar.aspx) (which returns `char`).

When in doubt, if the compiler suggests that there's a type problem, you should look at what it's expecting and what it's actually got - and work out which of those isn't what you expected.